# HTML responsive grid, with line under intermediate rows

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I need to have a layout presenting a grid of floating divs with an horizontal line under intermediate rows. There shouldn't be a line under the last row, and of course if there is only one row of elements, no line under it..

The problem is that size of the page is variable, my elements always have the same size, ergo there the number of columns is relative.

I know how to do this when i have the same number of columns, but not the variable ones.

This is a sketch for clarity:

[image: variable grid layout]
I am using bootstrap if that makes a difference..

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Where is the starting point in code? Please add a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, see also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: did you try last-child:

Comment: Could you please provide us with an example fiddle from jsfiddle.net?

Comment: If you use the last-child from a row you use in bootstrap, you can modify that appearance in css. read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

Comment: I did made some attempts, this is my best one, but I am still not happy, so i wanted to see if anyone has a better solution: https://jsfiddle.net/e125u41f/

Comment: the last-child is not that helpful as I need the entire last-row of children. Or maybe I am getting something wrong :)

Comment: Are you actually using one "row" that breaks or many rows?

Comment: yeah i was thinking of one row that breaks, but again, open to suggestions :)

Comment: Can you put your blocks into containers or no? Because if you can then just use `border-bottom`.

Comment: i can put them into containers, but how can i not put a border on the last line of blocks? ;)

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution (if you don't have a background image): 
Add the line under the units inside the flex container, and add an extra white line to overwrite the border of the bottom elements.

The divs in this example are just containers. Any padding and margin should be applied to elements inside them. I've made the units grey, and the bottom line light pink to show them, but in reality they should be transparent and white respectively.

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eee;
  width: 140px;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 10px;
  
  border-bottom: 3px solid red;
}

.container::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #FFF; /* Make this white. */
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div><div>A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: cool, thanks, but that last line is still visible in a "faded look"

Comment: Yes. That's to give you insight in the solution I used. That's why the text says *: I've made the units grey, and the bottom line light pink to show them..."* and the code says *"`background-color: #FEE; /* Make this white. */`"* Change #FEE to #FFF and it's white.

Comment: I've updated the answer too, to prevent further confusion.

Comment: aah I understand now, sorry for the confusion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, where the "black" `background-color` is equal to your body/container background colour.

https://jsfiddle.net/e125u41f/1/